# What server address to use in c# application of 5gbfree hosting server

Tags: c#, mysql

I have created a C# application. I want to connect to mysql. I am using 5gbfree server.  I don't know from where to get server address for connecting C# application to mysql database.

Comment: if you are running your server side code in your host's server you can use "localhost"

Comment: 1) Where is your application? Is it hosted remotely or it is in your local machine?
2) Where is your database? Is it hosted remotely or it is in your local machine?

Answer (score 0):

As part of your hosting plan you should have a cpanel where you can perform various admin tasks on your site.

As part of this overview it will state your hostname, such as

> myhost.5gbfree.com

This is then your server address.

[image]

According to [this FAQ post](https://www.5gbfree.com/faqs/how-do-i-connect-to-a-mysql-database/), then the other details you need are;

- database name = username_dbname
- database user = username_dbuser
- port = default (3306)
- database password = dbpassword

You should have also got all of these details in your signup/registration email.